# JAVA -HMACSHA256

Tags: java, encryption

HI i need to perform HMACSHA256 encryption please help me;

```
 sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("HMACSHA1"); //I get exception in this line (No algorithm found)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("hmacSHA256");
```

Hashing and Mac-ing are not encryption.

Answer (score -3):

try:

`sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("HMAC-SHA1");`

[Proof link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA)

Comment: If you ask for SHA-1 you will get SHA-1, not SHA-256. Also, if you talk to `MessageDigest` you will get a "message digest" (a hash function), not a MAC.